# Animate different view in a LinearLayout on Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I have a LinearLayout with some elements (A,B and C):

```
-------
|  A  |
+-----+
|  B  |
+-----+
|  C  |
-------
```

And at the beginning B is GONE (View.GONE), but when the user press A, B is shown with an animation:

```
public static LayoutAnimationController getLayoutAnimation_slideDownFromTop(Context ctx) {

      AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

      Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
      animation.setDuration(100);
      set.addAnimation(animation);

      animation = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
      );
      animation.setDuration(300);
      set.addAnimation(animation);

      LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0f);
      return controller;
}
```

The View B is animated propery, but the View C just jumps to the end and I would like to know if there is a standard way to animate B and C in a way that both of them swipe down at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android:animateLayoutChanges attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    ...
/>
```

Here is [the link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) with more information.

Comment: This works only wit API level 11 and I need it for API level 8